# C# database connection error on remote server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I used to run a C# website on my machine and I used this for database connection settings(Windows Authentification):

```
<add name="GPSEntities2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=GPS;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now I found an host for my website and they gave me these information :

```
Database server: Local MS SQL server
DB Name: mydbname_data   (just an example)
User: myuser_asd
Pass: mypassword
```

I tried various ways of changing the connection settings, but non of them worked.

The error I receive when doing an action that tries to access the database is:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'V-WIN13245\IWPD_15(mydbname)'.î
```

My question is how can I change this string(windows authentification on my machine)

```
<add connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

into an equivalent string that uses username & password on the host

Comment: Is that `IWPD_15` username your `User` from connection string?

Comment: can you please share the connection string?

Comment: Are you sure that when you deploy your solution to the host the right connection string is used? If you use VS to deploy you can specify the connection string on the publishing configuration dialog.

Comment: `V-WIN13245\IWPD_15(mydbname)` does not have permission to access the database you're attempting to connect to.  You can grant permission to this user in SQL Server

Comment: Post your C# code (include connection strings). Given the fact it's a remote server, some of the troubleshooting may be on their behalf to configure SQL and add relevant permissions etc., but we can start by checking the code at your end if you post it here.

Comment: Can you add code from this particular project please? Not a previous one. We need to see everything you can see (of relevance).

Comment: Sorry I had some <code> tags and the content between them was hidden when the question was displayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, i have field it according to your given info

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=mydbname_data;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser_asd;Password=mypassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

**P.S. if the server DB do not have `TCP/IP protocol` enabled then you can not access the DB using ip address from you dev environment. You can use the above connection string to connect to the db from you production environment.**

Comment: It is not local, it is a remote connection.

Comment: "Now I found an host for my website and they gave me these information : Database server: **Local** MS SQL server" as said by OP

Comment: If it was only for the website on the server, you would be right but he says "on my machine" at the beginning

Comment: I don't need a remote connection to the host. I need to configure the connection string for my website, which is on the host right now.

Comment: Thanks alot man. Your answer is perfect, but even so I had a stupid problem. I needed to change "GPSEntities2" not "LocalSqlServer" connection. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Add "Integrated Security=True;" in connection string and check it. Please refer [**SqlConnection.ConnectionString**].[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your datasource with the given host ip and the credentials with given username and password. If you still get the same error, you should check the given account with management studio, login properties. The connection string will be like this:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=your_server_ip_here;
Initial Catalog=your_database_name;User Id=your_database_username;
Password=your_database_password; Connection Timeout=1000000"/>
```